# Date formatting in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to convert date to specific format and subtract 2 hours from the time:

```
date 
2018-06-07 23:37:10
```

Expected output:

```
07Jun2018 21:37:10
```

I have tried it, but I got the below error:

> error:operator doesnt exist : Text -interval,might need to add explicit type cast.

Comment: SELECT '2018-06-07 23:37:10'::timestamp - INTERVAL '2 hours';

Comment: will it convert 2018-06-07 to 07Jun2018?

Comment: How do i derive a new column from '07Jun2018 21:37:10 '(data type text) based on time stamp(when time <12 then 'AM' else 'PM)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try using `TO_CHAR()` like this:

`SELECT TO_CHAR('2018-06-07 23:37:10'::TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '2 HOURS', 'DDMonYYYY HH24:MI:SS')`

(changed to HH24:MI as Oto Shavadze suggested)

[Here](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-to_char/) is the reference how to create patterns in case you need it in the future

Just remember that after the conversion the type of the value will be `text` so you won't be able to perform any other date-related functions (you have to do it before TO_CHAR()).

Comment: Just         `HH24:MI` instead of `HH:mm`

Comment: How do i derive a new column from '07Jun2018 21:37:10 '(data type text)based on time stamp(when time <12 then 'AM' else 'PM)

Comment: If you read the reference you will see there's a pattern you can use with `to_char()` `AM, am, PM, pm` any of those will actually yield the AM/PM