# Derive a new column based on Time stamp

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-date-functions, sqldatetime

I have a column 'customer_date' with datatype text.

Based on the time i need to derive a new column

Condition :

- when customer_date <12 then 'AM' else 'PM

```
customer_date

01Mar2018 10:03:54
02Mar2018 13:03:54
```

expected output

```
  customer_date             session

01Mar2018 10:03:54        AM
02Mar2018 13:03:54        PM
```

It throws me error when i wrote

```
select 
case EXTRACT(HOUR FROM customer_date)<12 then 'AM' else 'PM' end as session
from my table;
```

Comment: What error does your code generate?

Comment: According to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52102740/593144) you translating `timstamp` value to `text` and then trying to work with `text` value as with `timstamp`? IMO it is silly a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works when I test it:

```
select (case when EXTRACT(HOUR FROM customer_date::timestamp) < 12 then 'AM' else 'PM' end) as session
from mytable;
```

I added the explicit conversion and the `when`.

Answer (score 1):

You forget add `WHEN` in the `CASE WHEN` as @Gordon Linoff say.

There is a simple way, using [TO_CHAR](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/cc92a/4) instead of `CASE WHEN`.

use to `TO_CHAR`

> `AM, am, PM or pm` will get meridiem indicator (without periods)

```
CREATE TABLE myTable(customer_Date timestamp);

insert into myTable values ('01Mar2018 10:03:54'::timestamp);

insert into myTable values ('02Mar2018 13:03:54'::timestamp);
```

**Query 1**:

```
select customer_Date,TO_CHAR(customer_Date::timestamp, 'AM') as session
from mytable
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/cc92a/4/0)**:

```
|        customer_date | session |
|----------------------|---------|
| 2018-03-01T10:03:54Z |      AM |
| 2018-03-02T13:03:54Z |      PM |
```